# Precedence between config/database.yml and DATABASE_URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

When both config/database.yml and DATABASE_URL are present and are in conflict with each other, how is the conflict resolved in the case of Rails?  Is the answer different for RSpec?

Answer (score 1):

Based on testing with Rails 4.0.4, the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable takes precedence entirely for Rails. The reference to `DATABASE_URL` can be found in http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.0/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionHandling.html#method-i-establish_connection

Answer (score 0):

Rails always relies on config/database.yml. And since rspec loads the rails environment to run the specs, it behaves exactly the same way. Unless of course you are loading activerecord yourself, which I think it's not the case.

The use of the DATABASE_URL environment variable, is just a good practice [configuration scheme](http://12factor.net/config) to avoid putting sensitive data into revision control. What people generally do in practice, is to use the value defined in this variable to set the values in config/database.yml, e.g.

```
host: <%= ENV["DATABASE_URL"] %>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Except you'd have to use something like:

`host: <%= URI(ENV['DATABASE_URL']).host %>`

right?

Comment: I don't think so. Rails will parse the string representation of your url, e.g. postgres://username:password@localhost:5432/my_database.

Comment: Rails won't parse it for you, in `database.yml` file `host` should be the host, not URL. @PeterAlfvin is right, you need to extract the `host` part from URL.